# Facebook like button hijacking my url and changing it so something else?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, phishing

I want to add a facebook like button on `www.foldablehats.com` to `www.foldablehats.com` but despite the og tags and other markup the like comment references `http://education.apwg.org/r/en/index.htm`

http://jsfiddle.net/mwJkv/

What gives?  When I change the markup to say google, it works fine.  When I change it back to `www.foldablehats.com` it redirects to some weird phishing link at `education.apwg.org`.  Has facebook flagged this url as phishing?  I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Can’t confirm any of that looking at the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foldablehats.com%2F

Comment: FWIW, the recommended practice for like buttons is to either point to a content item or the brand's page on facebook ( ie: facebook.com/foldablehats or whatever ).  this way, you're easily able to send out messages to people who like the page/site.  if you have the site's like as the public url, they're only liking an opengraph page -- not an on-facebook entity that can message.

Comment: wow, it seems to be working now... did someone at fb read this and make a change I wonder?  If so, thanks!  @JonathanVanasco, I don't point to a facebook page because I have no intention of sending out messages.  I thought it would be more valuable to point directly to the website, no?  Most customers are new visitors and just buy once, and there are no new promotions that would require updating them.